# Watir Webdriver Text Input Slow on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, cucumber, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I'm using Cucumber and Watir-Webdriver to create some automated tests. I am also using the PageObject gem.  Some Example code is below

```
require 'page-object'

class LoginPage
    include PageObject

    text_field(:username, :name => 'username')
    text_field(:password, :name => 'password')
    link(:login, :text => 'SIGN IN')
end

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto "MyWebAppLoginScreen"
login_page = LoginPage.new(browser)
login_page.username="MyUserName"
login_page.password="MyPass"
login_page.login
```

The Problem that I'm seeing is that it takes a really long time to input the text into the username/password fields in IE (Version 11).  I have also tested with Firefox and Chrome and the text is input immediately.  In IE, however, it enters the text character by character and each character takes roughly 10 - 15 seconds to be put in.  This drastically slows down the runtime of my tests in IE.  Has anyone else encountered this?  Any ideas on how to fix it?  I tried using the browser.speed = :zippy option but this does not seem to help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah it is the 64 bit IEDriverServer. Something about IE's content handling and other technical jargon. But I deleted the 64 bit driver and downloaded the 32 bit one and now it is working just as well as chrome and firefox. Here is a link to all the files.

http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Also note for work reasons I am using IE10 but its something to try if your on IE11

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @TooSuspiciousToSignUpD
your given solution work like a charm with IE 11 as well.

Steps to follow:

1. Install IE 11 (Windows 7 64 bit version, don't download Developer / windows server 2008 version, you can find offline download of Windows 7 64 bit version from Microsoft site through google)
2. go to link as given by @TooSuspiciousToSignUpD
   (http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)
3. Click on "2.45" folder
4. Download IEDriverServer Win32 2.45.0.zip
5. unzip and put into your PATH (where original IEDriver is located, replace it with above)
6. run your script, it will work fast with Input text

Answer (score 0):

I do not think Internet Explorer 11 is supported. From [selenium-developers Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-developers/NUZuYb5Aaac):

> IE 11 support continues to be blocked by changes in browser behavior.
>   Workarounds from Microsoft are unlikely to be forthcoming, due to the
>   recent announcement of the in-process development of a
>   Microsoft-authored driver for Internet Explorer 11 and beyond. Note
>   that the Microsoft driver will not be available in any form until the
>   W3C Specification for WebDriver progresses further in the spec
>   process. Furthermore, no timeline for release has been announced by
>   Microsoft, nor should one be expected.

Comment: Interesting.  The most recent version of the IEDriverServer is working with IE but it is just very slow.  The slowness seems to only affect entering text.  Why does Microsoft have to make everything difficult?

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas on a work around?  IE is one of the primary supported browsers by the Web-App that I work with as the majority of our clients use IE... don't ask me why.

Comment: I have tested this in IE 9 and 10 as well.  This happens in IE 10 and 11 but not in IE 9.  From looking at the notice on Selenium-developers group IE 10 should be supported.